# Json Response to pyodbc Better way

Tags: python, json, python-requests, pyodbc

This works, but I have to do 30 of 100 felids of the response. Is there a better way?

````
            for record in data:
            record["lastName"] = record["lastName"].replace("'","''")
            record["lastName"] = record["lastName"].replace("'","''")
            cursor.execute("Insert Into emp_temp (employeeId, firstName, lastName) values ('" + record["employeeId"] +"','"+ record["firstName"] + "','"+ record["lastName"] +"')")
            cursor.commit()
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()```
````

Comment: So `data` is essentially a list of dict?

Comment: data = json.loads(response.text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `json.loads()` is giving you a simple list of dict objects then that is precisely the format that can be directly consumed by SQLAlchemy:

```py
# https://stackoverflow.com/q/67129218/2144390
import json

import sqlalchemy as sa

response_text = '''\
[{"employeeId": 1, "firstName": "Gord", "lastName": "Thompson"},
 {"employeeId": 2, "firstName": "Bob", "lastName": "Loblaw"}]'''
data = json.loads(response_text)
print(type(data))  # <class 'list'>
print(type(data[0]))  # <class 'dict'>

engine = sa.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://@mssqlLocal64")

emp_temp = sa.Table("emp_temp", sa.MetaData(), autoload_with=engine)

with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(emp_temp.insert(), data)

# check results
with engine.begin() as conn:
    results = conn.execute(sa.text("SELECT * FROM emp_temp")).fetchall()
    print(results)
    # [(1, 'Gord', 'Thompson'), (2, 'Bob', 'Loblaw')]
```